# MS Word Save each page as separate PDF document named with specific text within the document

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I want to convert a Microsoft excel table of invoice data and populating a mail merge template and once it is merged, I need to split up each invoice and save it as a pdf.

The code below does what I want but saves them as 1,2,3 etc.  The name I would like to be used is the invoice number found on the document (the first 8 characters of each page excluding header).

This is what my code looks like now:

```
 Sub BreakOnPage()
     Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by page.
     Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage

     For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

     'Select and copy the text to the clipboard.
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy

     ' Open new document to paste the content of the clipboard into.
     Documents.Add
     Selection.Paste
     ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the page, if any.
     Selection.TypeBackspace
     Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
     Selection.TypeBackspace
     Selection.Delete Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
     Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

     Dim strInvoiceNumber As String
     Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     With Selection.Find
     .ClearFormatting
     Text:="^#^#^#^#^#^#^#^#"
     .Forward = True
     .MatchWildcards = False
     .Execute
     End With

     ' Defines the DocNum

     strInvoiceNumber = Selection.Text


     ' Exports the document to a pdf file and saves in sequence starting at 1 and closes the word document without saving

     ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
     "C:\Users\MLock\Documents\MacrosDocs\" & strInvoiceNumber & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
     wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
     wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
     Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
     CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
     BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False


     ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

     ' Move the selection to the next page in the document.
     Application.Browser.Next
     Next i
     ' ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
 End Sub
```

How do I set the name of the PDF document here?

Answer (score 2):

So, you have to find the invoice number on the page and assign it to a variable, which you can then use to replace docnum.

Two ways to do the find are using Selection.Find, Executing the Find, and then assigning the variable to the Selection.Text.  That would probably be easiest.

You could also use Regular Expressions, capture the first 8 characters in a backreference, and use that.

I can clarify any of these points if you need it, not sure of your level of expertise.

Here is some code to accomplish what I think you are trying to do.  I assume that Selection.HomeKey Unit:wdStory is referring to the document containing the invoice number.

```
Sub BreakOnPage()
    Dim strInvoiceNumber as String
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text:="^#^#^#^#^#^#^#^#"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute
    End With
```

Now your 8 digit invoice number will be selected.  Assign the variable strInvoiceNumber to the Selection.Text, like so:

```
strInvoiceNumber = Selection.Text
```

And now use strInvoiceNumber in your ExportAsFixedFormat statement, instead of DocNum.

Good luck.

Comment: zero expertise, i would greatly appreciate any additional assistance you can provide. the first option seems great. what are the next steps?

Comment: again thank you, the line beginning with Text:="^#... is giving me a compile error

Comment: You need a period before Text, so it is included in the With statement.